# Maven parallel build wrong order

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin, parallel-builds

I'm trying to speed up my maven build with parallel processing. The project is multi-modular with nested modules. The structure is like:

- parent

  - m1
  - m2
  - sub-parent (a project that doesn't generate an artifact, but a folder with resources for m3 to use)
  - m3

**Edit**: now I even see, that at least once m3 did its copying goal before sub-parent even starts, thus used the result of previous build before sub-parent started its clean.

If I do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=my.packages.*` I see that sub-parent is correctly listed in the dependencies of m3. However, sometimes (rarely) parallel build `mvn -T 1C clean install` fails, because m3 build is being executed earlier than sub-parent.

Is there a workaround to enforce order? I know you can't set it directly. The thing is, I cant put sub-parent as a dependency to m3, because it doesn't have an artifact. And I don't sure I need it, because dependency tree shows that maven knows about this dependency.

**Edit:** I've added a sample minimal project. https://github.com/Imaskar/build-order . Except that sub/keystore need to be swapped for real one. Interestingly, here dependency tree doesn't show sub as a dependency of m3. How to tell m3 to depend on it, despite the fact that sub is not built to a jar file?

Comment: First if you have resources in a different module than they are used this is the first mistake...furthermore if you say "sub parent" does that mean you have packaging "pom" ?

Comment: Every project here has a `pom.xml`. The sub-parent one gathers artifacts from some other modules and signs them. m3 copies the result to itself. If m3 would do that, unnecessary jars would come along.

Comment: What do you mean by "gathers" artifacts? And sign them? Can you make and example project which shows the given situation? Apart from that if m3 builds earlier than sub-parent your dependencies between the modules are wrong.

Comment: Gathers=copies to its folder by declaring them as dependencies. Then maven-jarsigner-plugin is fired over that folder. This strucure is kinda ad-hoc to be able to build project as a descktop app and as a jnlp web app. I'll try to make an example, but it'll take a while.

Comment: https://github.com/Imaskar/build-order

Comment: If you need to be sure having build sub-parent before m3 you simple have to define a dependency to sub-parent in m3 which makes sense cause the sub-parent will be used in m3.....

Comment: if defined as a dependency, it fails with something like "could not resolve sub-parent.jar", because sub-parrent does not produce jar artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out some time ago,  but wanted for anyone to take the credit. The solution is declaring a dependency with

```
<type>pom</type>
```